# Quoted Titles & Possessives -- Journalistic Style

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, question-mark, saxon-genitive, exclamation-mark

The Associated Press (they never use italics) punctuates the possessive of titles in quotes like this:

> "Jeopardy!'s" subtleties of language ... . (actual excerpt from The AP)

If a question mark were used, would we do the possessive of the title in quotes like this? Yes or no?

> "Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf?'s" followers ... .

I think the example above exactly follows the pattern of punctuation (with the question mark) as it does with the exclamation point. Yay or nay?

Comment: But isn't it better than *"Jeopardy!"'s* ? Or *"Jeopardy"!'s* ?

Comment: Much better, Peter. Those examples of yours are confusing and really don't follow the AP's original example: "Jeopardy!'s" subtleties of language

Answer (score 1):

It should follow the same pattern as the exclamation. So, yay!

Comment: Yay! Thank you! Has anyone ever seen these punctuated as such? The AP places the whole possessive title within quotes! Weird, right?

Comment: I didn't get the last part of your comment. Can please give an example of the alternative way you think?

Answer (score 0):

1.Always include the punctuation mark inside the quotation marks.

2.Is the word *followers* part of the title? If so, then include it in the quotation marks with the question mark behind it.

To further clarify,  I'm not sure if you're trying to say "Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf's?" followers 
OR
"Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf's Followers?"

Good Luck!
~Krissy

Comment: No, Krissy, "followers" is not part of the title. So I believe it should be "Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf?'s" followers, with a possessive apostrophe directly following the question mark as shown in this example. And the ending quotes follow the "s" as shown, too.

Comment: I was trying to find an excerpt from The AP, with a quoted title and its possessive following the question mark. I could find only an example from the AP with the exclamation point (the "Jeopardy!'s" example). If anyone sees an example from the AP with a question mark used in the possessive of a quoted title, could you please supply the link here? Much gratitude.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean.  No-definitely don't put the question mark before the possessive s.  Jeopardy! has the exclamation mark there because the exclamation mark is actually part of the word.  It's trademarked that way.

Comment: I wasn't finished but I accidentally hit enter-sorry.  Anyway the exclamation mark is actually part of the word Jeopardy! which is why they have the apostrophe and s after the exclamation mark.  I'm 100% sure you should write "Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf's?"